# SalesforceException: Error unmarshaling response

Tags: apache-camel, salesforce, jbossfuse, soql, fuseesb

I am working on camel application. I am using SOQL to get the data from Salesforce.

I am using the below component

String soql = "SELECT ApiVersion,  CreatedById, CreatedDate, EventType, Id, LogFileFieldNames, LogDate FROM EventLogFile"  ;
salesforce:createBatchQuery?sObjectQuery=soql

**The above one is working.**,

But if i include **LogFile field** in the query, it means

String soql = "SELECT ApiVersion,  CreatedById, CreatedDate, EventType, Id, LogFileFieldNames, **LogFile**, LogDate FROM EventLogFile"  ;

or

public static final String soql  = "SELECT LogFile FROM EventLogFile"  ;

I am getting Caused by: **org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.api.SalesforceException: Error unmarshaling response**

Reason is: **LogFile has the value like /services/data/v58.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/a6F3s000000tTaldAv**. I think, / is causing the issue.

How to over come this issue?

Comment: Can you change the API used? Sounds like it's over REST API. SOAP API would return you the actual content of the file in this column, base64-encoded. Or you can "guess" the url yourself, it'll be `/services/data/{current SF api version}/sobjects/EventLogFile/{record id}` so maybe you can run the normal query, craft these urls and then access them (HTTP GET) to pull the payload.